# apache2 mod_proxy_uwsgi internal server error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, uwsgi

I have run uwsgi service. uwsgi run on localhost:3031 and works ok (tested via http).

```
# apache2 -v  
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
# uwsgi --version
2.0.9
```

I have a [mod_proxy_uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Apache.html#mod-proxy-uwsgi), compiled with apxs2 from https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/apache2/mod_proxy_uwsgi.c

and a config site apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@site.org
ServerName site
ServerAlias www.site.org

ProxyPass / uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031/

Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/media/static/robots.txt
Alias /media/static/admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin.
Alias /media/ /srv/www/media/

</VirtualHost>
```

And it does not work. I've got a "internal server error" from apache, no access logs from uwsgi, no error\access logs from apache2. only error via http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to "damjan" from irc uwsgi!

erro in uwsgi config

```
[uwsgi]

http = 127.0.0.1:3031
```

should be

```
[uwsgi]

socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
```